# Change the query of the search filter of the course enroll plugin (Moodle 3.5)

Tags: php, moodle

I am stuck in a place in moodle.

Default: When admin enrolls the student or teacher searching happens by name, email or username.

Changes to make: include default + search by registration number (which is in another table - **mdl_info_data**, all remaining data is in **mdl_user**  table) shown in screenshots

Here by default search filter runs by username, fullname or email id.

In the course setting I have been asked to add a new field named registration number whose data goes to the

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue.

If anyone facing similar issue in the future you can fix this by going to the page

**Page - project/enroll/locallib.php**

The query is split into two functions:

1. get_potential_users() - query is written - line 453 (approx)

   // added LEFT JOIN to create link between registration number - 16.01.2019
       $sql = " FROM {user} u
       LEFT JOIN {user_enrolments} ue ON (ue.userid = u.id AND ue.enrolid = :enrolid)
       LEFT JOIN {user_info_data} uid ON (uid.userid = u.id)
       WHERE $wherecondition AND ue.id IS NULL
       ";

**2. get_basic_search_conditions - where search where condition is added more (in my case I have added also search by registration number)**

```
// added the second where clause
$conditions[] = $DB->sql_fullname('u.firstname', 'u.lastname');
$conditions[] = 'uid.data'; // added for filtering by registration number - 16.01.2019
```

I have attached the locallib.php page as well for better understanding

You can follow this Moodle link for attached file as well :) .
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=380942#p1536136